# How can I create a JUnit 5 DynamicTest testSourceUri from a StackTraceElement?

Tags: junit5

[Minutest](https://github.com/dmcg/minutest) allows on-the-fly generation of JUnit 5 DynamicTests. I would like to be able to navigate to the code where the test is generated when the test is clicked in an IDE.

The [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests-uri-test-source) gives examples of URI's that can be used for this purpose. All I have at the point of test definition though is a [StackTraceElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html).

How can I use the information in the stack trace element to construct a suitable URI?

Comment: I've raised this as https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2635

Comment: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/pull/2637 should resolve this. I'll post an answer once that change has been released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a file URI by guessing at where the source would be.

```
private fun StackTraceElement.toSourceFileURI(sourceRoot: File): URI? {
    val fileName = fileName ?: return null
    val type = Class.forName(className)
    val fileUri = sourceRoot.toPath().resolve(type.`package`.name.replace(".", "/")).resolve(fileName).toUri()
    return URI(fileUri.scheme, fileUri.userInfo, fileUri.host, fileUri.port, "//" + fileUri.path, "line=$lineNumber", fileUri.fragment)
}
```

Given a sourceRoot of `src/test/java` this produces a URI that IntelliJ is able to follow when the test is double-clicked.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best you can do is target a `MethodSource` along the URI pattern

```
method:org.junit.Foo#bar(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])
```

This will only take you to the method of a test, though, which in Minutest's case is not optimal.

It is IMO a problem of Java, the language, not of JUnit 5, the platform. Java has no way to get a code location (through reflection) more accurately than pointing at a method. The one exception is an exception (pun intended). An exception's stack trace can point to an exact position within a method. That's why - in case of a failing assertion - most IDEs allow you to navigate to the line where a test's failure originated.

In rare cases like yours, where you have a stack trace element available at test definition time, JUnit could introduce something like a `FileLocationSource` and hope that IDE vendors will pick it up - although they haven't picked up other stuff from JUnit 5's API that's been present for a while. You might consider to create a github issue for JUnit 5 to convince them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution similar to @Duncan McGregor but in Java, as I had difficulty understanding his in Kotlin. I also made some modifications to stray away from using environment-specific path separators.

```
private URI uriToSource() throws ClassNotFoundException, URISyntaxException {
    final Path sourceFolderPath = Paths.get("src", "test", "java");
    final StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2];
    final Class<?> callingClass = Class.forName(stackTraceElement.getClassName());
    final String[] callingClassPathElements = callingClass.getPackage().getName().split("\\.");
    final Path sourceFilePackagePath = Paths.get(callingClassPathElements[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(callingClassPathElements, 1, callingClassPathElements.length));
    final URI uri = sourceFolderPath.resolve(sourceFilePackagePath).resolve(stackTraceElement.getFileName()).toUri();
    return new URI(uri + "?line=" + stackTraceElement.getLineNumber());
}
```

Using it would look like:

```
@TestFactory
public Collection<DynamicTest> someDynamicTests() throws URISyntaxException, ClassNotFoundException {

    return Stream.of(
                    DynamicTest.dynamicTest("Test one", uriToSource(), () -> Assertions.assertTrue(true)),
                    DynamicTest.dynamicTest("Test two", uriToSource(), Assertions::fail),
                    DynamicTest.dynamicTest("Test three", uriToSource(), () -> Assertions.assertTrue(true)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

On IntelliJ you can now click on the test and it would get you to the line

Comment: This works beautifully with Intellij, only problem is when you have unit/integration tests split into different source sets. In this case having a hardcoded root path won't work.